# add space around UITabelViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to add space around add UITabelViewCell in ios7 just like grouped table cell in ios6. Similar to facebook news-feed cell.

I have a custom UITableCell which i add to the tableView ( grouped). Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath i tried the following

```
int x = cell.frame.origin.x;
int y = cell.frame.origin.y;
int h = cell.frame.size.height;
int w = cell.frame.size.width;

NSLog(@" x : %i y : %i h = %i w = %i" , x, y , h, w);
CGRect newFram = cell.frame;
newFram.origin.x = 10;

cell.frame = newFram;
x = cell.frame.origin.x;
NSLog(@" x : %i y : %i h = %i w = %i" , x, y , h, w);
[[cell layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```

I tried to change the x orgin of the cell. When i print 'x' , its says 0 first and 10 second time but the cell is always at 0.

```
2013-11-04 22:07:30.334 iosproj[6256:70b]  x : 0 y : 0 h = 71 w = 320
2013-11-04 22:07:30.335 iosproj[6256:70b]  x : 10 y : 0 h = 71 w = 320

2013-11-04 22:07:30.337 iosproj[6256:70b]  x : 0 y : 0 h = 71 w = 320
2013-11-04 22:07:30.337 iosproj[6256:70b]  x : 10 y : 0 h = 71 w = 320
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: you not abel to change UITableCell,you set frame for your views in cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not answering the question directly, but if you really wanted custom design for your view and cells, you could use a `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell`s instead. You can then use a `UICollectionViewLayout` to handle the spacing between sections and cells. It's all very clear in the documentation for iOS.